# html file in django project not working properly

Tags: html, django, visual-studio-code

I am new to django, i created two folder static and templates in django project, i created a html file in templates folder index.html, but VS code is not working properly here, i.e not showing emmet and html tag suggestion as VS code suggest normally, while on other files of other project not belong to django , VS code working properly , please anyone know about it ?

Answer (score 0):

At the footer of the VS Code select language as html by default it is django HTML